# R precision in operations

Tags: r, ranks

If you try to calculate the difference between
`(9.1 - 8.9) - (6.9-6.7)` in R, you'll get

```
> (9.1 - 8.9) - (6.9-6.7)
[1] -8.881784e-16
```

I found this when I was trying to calculate ranks considering ties as average rank but I saw that because of precision issue, it don't consider the tie.

```
A <- c( 6.1, 5.5, 8.9, 7.4, 4.3, 9.7, 6.7, 9.4)
B <- c( 7.3, 5.5, 9.1, 7.0, 5.1, 9.8, 6.9, 9.8)
Z <- B - A
rank(abs(Z))
[1] 8.0 1.0 3.0 5.5 7.0 2.0 4.0 5.5
```

Expected result

```
[1] 8.0 1.0 3.5 5.5 7.0 2.0 3.5 5.5
```

Comment: This is R FAQ 7.31: [Why doesn’t R think these numbers are equal?](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/FAQ/R-FAQ.html#Why-doesn_0027t-R-think-these-numbers-are-equal_003f)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What @Stephan Kolassa said.

Round the difference appropriately before ranking

```
> A <- c( 6.1, 5.5, 8.9, 7.4, 4.3, 9.7, 6.7, 9.4)
> B <- c( 7.3, 5.5, 9.1, 7.0, 5.1, 9.8, 6.9, 9.8)
> Z <- round(B - A, 5)
> rank(abs(Z))
[1] 8.0 1.0 3.5 5.5 7.0 2.0 3.5 5.5
```